# Cutting out a mask from a image with ImageMagick

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to cut out a shape from an image based on a mask I have. I tried a number of ways but I'm really struggling to get the result I need.
I'm using ImageMagick 7.1.0-51 Q16-HDRI on Windows.

The "base" image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/06t9S.jpg

The mask i'm using:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXRco.jpg

Expected result(photoshoped):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij1eR.jpg

Edit: Reuploaded direct on imgur to maintain transparent background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Imagemagick, you want to invert (negate) the polarity of black and white, then do a -compose difference -composite, then invert again.

Hair:

[image]

Face:

[image]

```
magick hair.png face.png -alpha off -colorspace gray -negate -compose difference -composite -negate result.png
```

Result:

[image]

If you want pure white in the face area, threshold the two images after the conversion to grayscale

magick hair.png face.png -alpha off -colorspace gray -auto-threshold otsu -negate -compose difference -composite -negate result2.png

Result 2:

[image]

**ADDITION**

If your input images have transparent backgrounds, then you have to extract the alpha channels, combine them to do the difference and then put that alpha channel back on the input.

Unix Syntax:

```
magick hair.webp \
\( +clone face_mask.webp -alpha extract -compose difference -composite \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

For Windows,remove the \ in front of the parentheses and change the end of line \ to ^.

Comment: I just notice that SO replaced the transparent background with white background on the images. I just uploaded directly on imgur to preserve the transparent aspects. When I tried your suggestion with the transparent images it became just a black and white blocks. Is there a way to make it works with transparency? Also, the idea is to have the face cutout transparent as well

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer above.

Comment: Absolute legend. Thank you!

Comment: Just found a problem with this, if the mask is bigger than the background it's put uppon, the excess will be black. You can see the left eartip on the result image that happening. Any suggestions on how to improve this? I mean, just cutout if there's something on the background, if it's transparent, then it stays transparent

Comment: Pad the input with its background color using -bordercolor ... -border ... so that it is the size of the mask and positioned correctly.